# Receive "connection refused" when I try to run a Docker Container with NFS Volume

Tags: docker, nfs, docker-volume

I'm working with NFS Volume.
I created a NFS server and on my rasberry pi I set the client and if I mount the directory exposed I can see the content, It's mean that the configuration works.

My goal is to create a volume with the following command:

```
 sudo docker volume create --driver local \
    --opt type=nfs \
    --opt o=addr=10.0.0.5,rw \
    --opt device=:/export/users/reddata \
    foo
```

As I saw in the documentation the create a NFS volume.
My problem is the follow, when I run the container:

`sudo docker run -it -p 1880:1880 -v foo:/data --name mynodered -d nodered/node-red`

I receive the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to mount local volume: mount :/export/users/reddata:/var/lib/docker/volumes/foo/_data, data: addr=10.0.0.5: connection refused.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I this that something it's not authorized, but I also think that I can mount my shared directory on my pi the configuration previous did should works.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks for your time

Alessandro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
The problem was the way to create the volume, the right way is:

```
sudo docker volume create --driver local \
--opt type=nfs \
--opt o=addr=10.0.0.5,nfsvers=4 \
--opt device=:/export/users/reddata \
foo
```

It's necessary to specify  the nfsvers=4.

Another important configuration, in my case it's not necessary to supervise the host that access my folder, in the server my /etc/exports it the follow:

export/users/reddata *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,insecure)

With the *, I specify all IPs on the network.

Best Regards

Alessandro